# Excel: SUMIF by year for large dataset

Tags: excel

I have a large Excel sheet spanning many years of data laid out in the following format:

```
          1/2012    2/2012  3/2012  4/2012  5/2012
```

USA
Canada
Japan
UK

I need to sum the fields to obtain annual totals. What I have tried is something along the lines of:

=SUMIF(A3:A7,"YEAR(A3:A7)=2012")

But it returns 0.

Would greatly appreciate advice on the proper form (to replicate across years), or some alternative method. Many thanks.

Comment: Add a row below the dates for the year.  Then look into using pivot tables for your reporting.

Comment: So do you have different numbers (e.g. amounts of money) in each column that you want to summarise in a table by year and country?

Comment: Yes, that is basically what I want to do. Thanks